# PGRFileManager Minimizes in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ckeditor

I have a really unusual problem with PGRFilManager plugin (http://pgrfilemanager.sourceforge.net/) for CKeditor (http://ckeditor.com/)

This only happens in Google Chrome, when I choose 'Browser Server' in the 'Image Properties' window of CKeditor to open PGRFileManager, it opens, but then instantly minimizes to the task bar in Windows.

Has anyone else come about this problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug in Chrome 18 (it works fine in 17 and 19), there's a workaround included in [CKEditor 3.6.3](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_3.6.3_released)